# Node.js Discord Bot TypeError: Cannot read property of 'voice' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Here is my whole code for the command, the problem is when I do -move everyone 123132123123(example channel id). The command works perfectly but gives me an error of `(node:317) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'voice' of undefined`. I have been trying to  `.catch()` the error but it still gives me that error. Whenever I do `` return member.voice.setChannel(`${move}`); ``. The error stops but also only moves me for some reason...

```js
if (command === 'move') {
  if (!message.member.permissions.has("MOVE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send(':x: **You do not have the permission to use this command!**');
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const mem = message.mentions.members.first()
  let move = args[1]; // Remember arrays are 0-based!.
  let move2 = args[2];
  let idcheckchannel1 = client.channels.cache.get(move)
  let idcheckchannel2 = client.channels.cache.get(move2)
  if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please mention user and voice channel ID/IDs')
  if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Please mention voice channel ID/IDs')

  if(args[0] === 'everyone' && !move2) {
    if (!idcheckchannel1) return message.channel.send('Please use a valid voice channel ID')
    let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(message.member.voice.channel.id);
    for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members)
      member.voice.setChannel(`${move}`);
  }

  if (!mem.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('User is not in voice channel')

  if (!move2) {
    if (!idcheckchannel1) return message.channel.send('Please use a valid voice channel ID')
    mem.voice.setChannel(`${move}`)
  } else {
    if (!idcheckchannel1) return message.channel.send('Please use a valid voice channel ID')
    if (!idcheckchannel2) return message.channel.send('Please use a valid voice channel ID')
    mem.voice.setChannel(`${move}`)
    mem.voice.setChannel(`${move2}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mem` may be `undefined` if `message.mentions.members` is empty. You should check whether `mem` is undefined or not before using it.

Try this:

```js
if (command === 'move') {
  if (!message.member.permissions.has("MOVE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send(':x: **You do not have the permission to use this command!**');
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const mem = message.mentions.members.first()
  let move = args[1]; // Remember arrays are 0-based!.
  let move2 = args[2];
  let idcheckchannel1 = client.channels.cache.get(move)
  let idcheckchannel2 = client.channels.cache.get(move2)
  if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please mention user and voice channel ID/IDs')
  if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Please mention voice channel ID/IDs')

  if(args[0] === 'everyone' && !move2) {
    if (!idcheckchannel1) return message.channel.send('Please use a valid voice channel ID')
    let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(message.member.voice.channel.id);
    for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members)
      member.voice.setChannel(`${move}`);
  }

  if (mem != null) { // << ensure that mem is not undefined
    if (!mem.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('User is not in voice channel')

    if (!move2) {
      if (!idcheckchannel1) return message.channel.send('Please use a valid voice channel ID')
      mem.voice.setChannel(`${move}`)
    } else {
      if (!idcheckchannel1) return message.channel.send('Please use a valid voice channel ID')
      if (!idcheckchannel2) return message.channel.send('Please use a valid voice channel ID')
      mem.voice.setChannel(`${move}`)
      mem.voice.setChannel(`${move2}`)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I first got a error of  ``SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'``, then I had fixed it by putting an extra ``}`` at the end of the everyone line. Then now it gives me this error of ``(node:134) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: mem is not defined`` which is weird because isn't what the ``if (mem != null)`` supposed to prevent?

Comment: Maybe you add `}` at the wrong place. I have edited my answer to complete code. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I did add the ``}`` at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

[`channel.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) returns a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), not an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), so array destructuring will not work. Even if it did, the first properties of each element are not `memberID` and `member`.

Also, you made a new `channel` variable, even though you already had the channel object.

```js
// let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(message.member.voice.channel.id);
// for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members)
//  member.voice.setChannel(`${move}`);
// };

for (const member of message.member.voice.channel.members) 
 member.voice.setChannel(move);
```

Comment: I have changed my code to 
``if(args[0] === 'everyone' && !move2) {
                if (!idcheckchannel1) return message.channel.send('Please use a valid voice channel ID')
      for (const member of message.member.voice.channel.members) 
 member.voice.setChannel(move);
        }`` 
but now it says ``(node:347) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setChannel' of undefined``. Edit sorry for it being messy I don't get how to do the  thing